ReferenceError Error when trying to import anything other then Jquery
I am trying to make jquery globally available on all pages.
I am using Vite to build the js bundle, I works well when only import in files are jquery.
When i add anyhting other then jquery, like jquery validation or jquery ui it dosent work
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';
import vitePluginRequire from 'vite-plugin-require';

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'jquery-validate': 'assets/js/lib/jquery.validate.js',
            'jquery-validate-unobtrusive':
                'assets/js/lib/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js',
            'jquery-validate-tritaccustom':
                'assets/js/lib/jquery.validate.tritaccustom.js',
        },
    },

    plugins: [
      
        vitePluginRequire(),
    ],
    server: {
        open: false, // Prevent Vite from looking for index.html
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'assets/build',

        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                format: 'iife',
                entryFileNames: '[name].js',
                assetFileNames: '[name].js', // Output format for browser compatibility
                chunkFileNames: '[name].js',
            },
            input: 'assets/app/main/index.js', // Entry point for JavaScript
        },
    },
});



index.js
// works 
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;


$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('jQuery is ready and bound globally!');
 
});



if i try to import any other library in index.js , it gives me ReferenceError

